# recursive php category tree extended

Tags: php, mysql, database, recursion

I have been searching all over the forum but could not locate the answer to my specific question. I hope you can help me, for it has taken me  A LOT of time to figure this out as a beginning PHP programmer.

I have a page that listens to this URL : .../.../edit_cat.php?id=24

I want to have a nice category tree. I have accomplished this, but I want all categories with no children to be a link to page post.php and all parent that do have children to be a link but only to show the other categories. Some sort of dropdown menu you might call it. So no children is post.php and if has children then drop the rest of children down. I hope this makes it clear...This is whay I have so far. It works as a tree but not how I wish it to be:

```
 <h2>This is the current category tree</h2>
 <?php
 category_tree(0);



 function category_tree($catid){
 include '../config/connect.php';

 $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '".$catid."'");
 $result->execute();

 while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
 $i = 0;
 if ($i == 0){ echo '<ul class="cattree">';}

 echo '<li><a href="category.php?id=' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_title'] . '</a>';
  category_tree($row['cat_id']);
  echo '</li>';
 $i++;
 if ($i > 0){ echo '</ul>'; }

 endwhile;
}
?>
```

My table of categories looks like this:

```
 cat_id    |    cat_title    |    parent_id

    1          some_title              0
    2          some_title              1
    3          title!                  2
    4          main_title              0
    5          titellos!               4
```

Comment: What's wrong with the results of your current code?

Comment: That's a kind of abuse of a prepared statement!!

Comment: @Strawberry: it's cargo-cult programming. using something without ever really understanding how/why to use the tool properly.

Comment: @TabAlleman it does not give me the oppurtunity to give do the following: When parent has children change <a href="#">. When parent has no children <a href="cat.php?id=#">

Comment: @Strawberry I know I am not using it properly. I am still learning, but thanks for pointing it out, I will dive into that as well.

Comment: So if the results of your query included a "HasChildren" column, that would solve the problem?

Comment: @TabAlleman If you mean what I think you mean, yes it would. So HasChildren can have other styling than HasNoChildren.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I did last year, a query returns each line, with the idx, parent_idx and label of the line.

First call:

```
print_list(1, 0, $lines);
```

Function:

```
function print_list($parent, $level, $ar) {

    $children = filter_by_parent($parent, $ar);
    if (empty($children)) {
        return;
    }

    echo '<ul>';

    foreach ($children as $child) {

        include PATH_PUBLIC . 'clients/simili/line.php';

        print_list($child['Child_Idx'], ($level + 1), $ar);

        echo  '</li>';

    }

    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Second function:

```
function filter_by_parent($parent_id, $ar){
    $retval = array();
    foreach($ar as $a) {
        if ($a['Parent_Idx'] == $parent_id) {
            $retval[] = $a;
        }
    }
    return $retval;
}
```

And the html called in the function:

```
<li class="no" data-id="<?php echo $child['Child_Idx']; ?>" data-parent-id="<?php echo $child['Parent_Idx']; ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-minus-square-o"></i>
    &nbsp;
    <span class="name">
        <label><?php echo $child['Child_Name']; ?></label>
        <a href="<?php echo url(''); ?>clients/simili/detail.php?uo=<?php echo $child['Child_Idx']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-book" title="Détails de l'Unité d'Organisation"></a></i>
    </span>
    <div class="chiffres">
        <span class="inscrits"><?php echo $child['Nb_Collab']; ?></span>
        <span class="etp-collab"><?php echo $child['ETP_Collab']; ?></span>
        <span class="etp-postes"><?php echo $child['ETP_Postes']; ?></span>
        <span class="etp-unit"><?php echo $child['ETP_Unit']; ?></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is the mysql query you used for this ? And where did you place it ? I am quite new to this, so would be great If you can help me with that little bit. Then I can try if this works. Maybe fiddle ?

Comment: You just get a query with your fields (idx, parent idx, label of the line) One line per idx. Then you use this array on the recursive function.

Comment: I have tried many many times, but because I am just a beginner. Could you make an example for me with a query. In fiddle ? Maybe using my table in the main question ? I hope you can assist me, would be great!!!

Comment: I hope someone can assist in this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't know anything about PHP, but here's how you can add a "HasChildren" column to your sql query:

```
SELECT c.*, 
CASE
  WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Categories c1 WHERE c1.parent_id=c.cat_id) THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END AS HasChildren
FROM Categories c
WHERE ParentID = @CatID
```